# Parameters in function, some of them are optional some required

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function where I have some parameters, some of them are optional some required, e.g.

```
example(page: number, perPage: number, name?: string, status?: boolean) {
    // Body
}
```

Sometimes I call it with only `status`

```
example(1, 25, true);
```

It means that `true` there will be as `name` what is not the way I want to do this. Changing order in function declaration doesn't help because sometimes I only got the `name`.

I was trying something like this, and in my service check if parameter is not equal to null.

```
example(1, 25, null, true);
```

example.service.ts

```
example(page: number, perPage: number, name?: string, status?: boolean) {
    if (name !== null) {
        // body
    }
    if (status !== null) {
       // body
    }
}
```

But I don't think it's the best way to handle this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure, but have you tried passing object instead of list of arguments?

```
example(data: {page: number, perPage: number, name?: string, status?: boolean}) {
  //code goes here
}
example({page: 1, perPage: 25, status: true})
```

In this case you will get exact value you passed in the object

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can handle this. The first one is by passing the third argument as undefined

```
example(1, 25, undefined, true);
```

Another way is to accept a single argument which is an object

```
interface Options {
  page: numberl; perPage: number; name?: string; status?: boolean;
}
```

This makes your function behave like it takes in named arguments.

```
example({page: 1, perPage: 25, status: true});

// in your function you can use destructuring for brevity

interface Options {
  page: number; perPage: number; name?: string; status?: boolean;
}

example(options: Options) {
   const {page, perPage, name, status} = options
    // Body
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you don't pass any value to an optional parameter, their value becomes `undefined` (Source: [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters)). So you can just pass `undefined` for that particular parameter.

To call `example()` with only `status`

```js
example(1, 25, undefined, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply Pass just param in the form of object and iterate that object in method

```
example(paramObj) {
    //iterate params here
    let paramArr = Object.keys(paramObj)

}

//calling
example({name:'Xyz Person'});
```